# Send several JSON objects in one request

Tags: elasticsearch, rust

I have been trying to conduct a multi-search (where I am able to send several json objects at once) but have failed so far.

This request is going to an Elasticsearch server but even if you don't know what that is you can still help.

I want to have a request body that looks like this:

```
{"index": "superheroes"}
{"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": "hulk"}}}}
{"index": "superheroes"}
{"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": "spiderman"}}}}
{"index": "superheroes"}
{"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": "ant man"}}}}
```

Notice the JSON objects are not wrapped with an array.

If I send that exact block via a client such as Postman, I get the desired output from the server.

Here is what I am doing in Rust to send that request:

```
let mut request_pieces: Vec<serde_json::Value> = Vec::new();

        for name in names {
            request_pieces.push(json!({"index": "superheroes"}));
            request_pieces.push(json!({"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": name}}}}));
        }

        let search_body: Value = json!(request_pieces);
        println!("{:?}", search_body);
```

When I send that I get an error from the server, it makes sense as it is inside an array and the server is not expecting that, what I am sending to the server looks like the following:

```
Array([
Object({
    "index": String(
        "superheroes",
    ),
}),
Object({
    "query": Object({
        "term": Object({
            "name": Object({
                "term": String(
                    "hulk",
                ),
            }),
        }),
    }),
}),
Object({
    "index": String(
        "superheroes",
    ),
}),
Object({
    "query": Object({
        "term": Object({
            "name": Object({
                "term": String(
                    "spiderman",
                ),
            }),
        }),
    }),
}),
Object({
    "index": String(
        "superheroes",
    ),
}),
Object({
    "query": Object({
        "term": Object({
            "name": Object({
                "term": String(
                    "ant man",
                ),
            }),
        }),
    }),
  }),
])
```

How can I send a request like the one at the very top? where the JSON objects are separated.

By the way, a way this was achieved in other programming languages was by making it all a string, but in Rust it is very challenging going to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a vector of json requests, instead of encoding that into a json string, you can directly obtain what you want:

```rust
let mut request_pieces = Vec::new();

for name in names {
  request_pieces.push(json!({"index": "superheroes"}).to_string());
  request_pieces.push(json!({"query": {"term": {"word": {"term": name}}}}).to_string());
}

let search_body = request_pieces.join("\n");
println!("{}", search_body);
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but even when implementing your recommendation I get the error: `Ok(Object({"error": Object({"col": Number(10), "line": Number(1), "reason": String("Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [index]."), "root_cause": Array([Object({"col": Number(10), "line": Number(1), "reason": String("Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [index]."), "type": String("parsing_exception")})]), "type": String("parsing_exception")}), "status": Number(400)))`

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. The snippet I gave you should produce the output you wanted. Have you checked that?

Comment: It should, as a matter of a fact, after printed, when I paste it on postman, I get the desired outcome...

Comment: This means you probably also have an other issue: how to properly deliver your JSON request to elasticsearch. I would suggest asking an other question if you need some help, as it seems to me it's a different issue from the one discussed in this thread.

Comment: my dumb mistake in another part of the code, it worked from the very start... sorry ‍️‍️‍️

Comment: Well, no problem, if it works then good for you ^^

Answer (score 0):

As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432234/1831, if you already have a [newline-delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/) string, which is [what the msearch API accepts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search-api-desc), the simplest way would be to pass this directly to the client

```rust
// construct the client however you need
let client = Elasticsearch::default();

let request_body = r#"{"index": "superheroes"}
{"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": "hulk"}}}}
{"index": "superheroes"}
{"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": "spiderman"}}}}
{"index": "superheroes"}
{"query": {"term": {"name": {"term": "ant man"}}}}
"#;

let msearch_response = client
    .msearch(MsearchParts::None)
    .body(vec![request_body])
    .send()
    .await?;

let json: Value = msearch_response.json().await?;
```

The `body` fn accepts a `Vec<T>` where `T` [implements the `Body` trait, which `&str` does.](https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/7.14.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/http/request/trait.Body.html)