# Msearch Elasticsearch API - Rust

Tags: elasticsearch, rust

By this point, I feel like I am the only other person on earth that is using multi-search on Rust... other than the person who wrote it.

There is zero documentation on this other than this hyper-confusing one https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/7.14.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/struct.Msearch.html

I figured I had to pass MsearchParts parts as an argument for the `client.msearch(here goes msearch_parts)`, and luckily for me, there a piece of [documentation](https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/7.14.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/enum.MsearchParts.html) for how that is supposed to be, but such documentation is so poorly done that I have no clue of what to do because I did not write the API.

I have no clue of how to pass my JSON

```
{"index":"cat_food"}
{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Whiskers"}}}}
{"index":"cat_food"}
{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Chicken"}}}}
{"index":"cat_food"}
{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Turkey"}}}}
"NOT IN THE CODE: extra EMPTY line required by elasticsearch multi-searches"
```

and get a 200^ response.

As a side note, my JSON is well formatted into a string that can be sent in a normal `reqwest` the issue is more on how to turn that JSON string into `MsearchParts`.

Comment: The MSearch API does not need a string at the end of the payload. It needs an empty line.

Comment: @Jeremy yes, I added that string for clarity, wasn't clear, my bad.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to summarize the documentation for you. You would get more help if you posted code showing the error you're seeing and asking a more specific question.

Comment: @Jeremy the documentation can't be summarized as there is barely any, so I need someone that can explain how to turn a JSON into a `MsearchParts` that can be passed down into the msearch() method.

Comment: You are right @XaviFont there is barely anything useful about this online, this post will serve as that in the future.

Comment: @Xavi So, what have you tried?

Comment: @Jeremy well, I have tried on passing the pure JSON formatted string (the ones that have a bunch of \\ \\ \\) and also I have tried on passing to MsearchParts::Index and MsearchParts::IndexType()  an object like it is done in the same method of elasticsearch for javascript... I have tried on directly passing a clean string on MsearchParts of one single msearch just because, did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

The body needs to conform to the structure specified for the [msearch API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search-api-desc)

> The multi search API executes several searches from a single API
> request. The format of the request is similar to the bulk API format
> and makes use of the newline delimited JSON (NDJSON) format.
>
> The structure is as follows:
>
> ```
> header\n
> body\n
> header\n
> body\n
> ```

```rust
let client = Elasticsearch::default();

let msearch_response = client
    .msearch(MsearchParts::None)
    .body::<JsonBody<Value>>(vec![
        json!({"index":"cat_food"}).into(),
        json!({"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Whiskers"}}}}).into(),
        json!({"index":"cat_food"}).into(),
        json!({"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Chicken"}}}}).into(),
        json!({"index":"cat_food"}).into(),
        json!({"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Turkey"}}}}).into(),
    ])
    .send()
    .await?;

let json: Value = msearch_response.json().await?;

// enumerate over the response objects in the response
for (idx, response) in json["responses"]
    .as_array()
    .unwrap()
    .into_iter()
    .enumerate()
{
    println!();
    println!("response {}", idx);
    println!();

    // print the name of each matching document
    for hit in response["hits"]["hits"].as_array().unwrap() {
        println!("{}", hit["_source"]["name"]);
    }
}
```

The above example uses `MsearchParts::None`, but because all search requests are targeting the same index, the index can be specified with `MsearchParts::Index(...)`, and it doesn't need to be repeated in the header for each search request

```rust
let client = Elasticsearch::default();

let msearch_response = client
    .msearch(MsearchParts::Index(&["cat_food"]))
    .body::<JsonBody<Value>>(vec![
        json!({}).into(),
        json!({"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Whiskers"}}}}).into(),
        json!({}).into(),
        json!({"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Chicken"}}}}).into(),
        json!({}).into(),
        json!({"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Turkey"}}}}).into(),
    ])
    .send()
    .await?;

let json: Value = msearch_response.json().await?;

// enumerate over the response objects in the response
for (idx, response) in json["responses"]
    .as_array()
    .unwrap()
    .into_iter()
    .enumerate()
{
    println!();
    println!("response {}", idx);
    println!();

    // print the name of each matching document
    for hit in response["hits"]["hits"].as_array().unwrap() {
        println!("{}", hit["_source"]["name"]);
    }
}
```

Because msearch's `body()` fn takes a `Vec<T>` where `T` implements the [`Body` trait](https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/7.14.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/http/request/trait.Body.html), and `Body` is implemented for `&str`, you can pass a string literal directly

```rust
let msearch_response = client
    .msearch(MsearchParts::None)
    .body(vec![r#"{"index":"cat_food"}
{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Whiskers"}}}}
{"index":"cat_food"}
{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Chicken"}}}}
{"index":"cat_food"}
{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Turkey"}}}}
"#])
    .send()
    .await?;

let json: Value = msearch_response.json().await?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [doc](https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/7.14.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/enum.MsearchParts.html) of `MsearchParts`, it looks an array of `&str` needs to be used to construct the `Index` (or `IndexType`) variant of `enum MsearchParts`. So, please give the following way a try and see if it works.

```
Let parts = MsearchParts::Index([
    r#"{"index":"cat_food"}"#, 
    r#"{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Whiskers"}}}}"#, 
    r#"{"index":"cat_food"}"#, 
    r#"{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Chicken"}}}}"#, 
    r#"{"index":"cat_food"}"#, 
    r#"{"query":{"term":{"name":{"term":"Turkey"}}}}"#
]);
```

Comment: `*Parts` enums are used to model the URL variants for APIs. See https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/7.14.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/#making-api-calls

Answer (score 0):

After hours of investigating I took some other approach, using a body vector and the msearch API.
I think the json doesnt go to the msearchparts but to a vector of bodies.
(see https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/7.14.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/#request-bodies)

It runs, but the response gives me an error 400. And I dont know why.
I assume its the missing empty (json) bodies, as required in the elastic console.

What do you think?

```
let mut body: Vec<JsonBody<_>> = Vec::with_capacity(4);
body.push(json!(
    {"query": {
        "match": {"title":"bee"}
    }}
).into());

body.push(json!(
    {"query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "tree",
            "fields": ["title", "info"]
            }
    },"from":0, "size":2}
).into());

let search_response = client
    .msearch(MsearchParts::Index(&["nature_index"]))
    .body(body)
    .send()
    .await?;
```